# Golang channel: timeout pattern not work as example

Tags: go, channel

I try to implement [Timeout pattern](https://gobyexample.com/timeouts) for my project. Here is an example code of above link:

```
c1 := make(chan string, 1)
go func() {
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    c1 <- "result 1"
}()

select {
case res := <-c1:
    fmt.Println(res)
case <-time.After(1 * time.Second):
    fmt.Println("timeout 1")
}
```

Another example is:

```
c2 := make(chan string, 1)
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
        c2 <- "result 2"
    }()
    select {
    case res := <-c2:
        fmt.Println(res)
    case <-time.After(3 * time.Second):
        fmt.Println("timeout 2")
    }
```

I can run this example successfully. Then I try apply this to my project. Here is my project code:

```
for {
    select {
    case ev := <-c.EventChannel():
        // do something here
    case <-time.After(2 * time.Second):
        // this condition never happend
        return
    default:
       // do nothing as non-blocking channel pattern
    }
}
```

But I don't know why code never run into timeout case. When I move `time.After(2 * time.Second)` into separate statement, it works. Here is modified code:

```
timeout := time.After(2 * time.Second)
for {
    select {
    case ev := <-c.EventChannel():
        // do something here
    case <-timeout:
        require.Equal(t, "time out after 2s", "")
    default:
        // do nothing as non-blocking channel pattern
    }
}
```

I don't know the differences between 2 cases. And why first example works. Please help me figure out.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the select statement wont wait if there is a default case, so in your case it just checks for `EventChannel` and goes to default case because it is not blocking and it wont wait for `2 seconds timeout`. In every iteration there is a `2 secs` timeout , so it never get executed.

In the second case as the timer is outside the loop it wont reinitialize in each iteration so after `2 seconds` select statement will catch that signal and executes timeout.

If you want to wait for `2 secs` in each iteration then you can do something like this

```
for {
  select {
  case ev := <-c.EventChannel():
      // do something here
  default:
      // do nothing as non-blocking channel pattern
  }
  time.Sleep(2 *time.Second)
```

}

Comment: Can you explain for me behavior of first example ? I think in first example, when we write `case <-time.After(1 * time.Second)`, it doesn't wait  for 2 seconds.

Comment: @TrầnKimDự Yes select never waits when you have a `default` case. So it just checks for messages in all the cases if nothing is there it just executes default and exits. As in the first case, for timeout to happen it needs to wait for `2 secs` so it never gets executed

Comment: Can you look at my second example (I just edited) that I copied from golang example. If `case <-time.After(3 * time.Second)` will block for 3 seconds, why can it print "result 2" in that case ? Thanks.

Comment: @TrầnKimDự whichever case got the signal first will be executed. If both cases got the signal at the same time then case will be executed pseudo-randomly, there is no order of execution. As `c2 <- "result 2"` this will be done before timeout this case will get executed

Comment: Thanks. I understood. Just one more question, so in a block with default, Golang doesn't allow to run "waiting statement" so Golang will bypass that statement. (so we must initialize outside) ?

Comment: Yes that's correct. With non-blocking select pattern you cant have explicit wait inside any case